# Animate stacked flexbox elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a menu where some buttons appear when the a button is clicked. Now all these buttons are stacked on top of each other and when the button is clicked the other buttons slide into place.

https://jsfiddle.net/ck1ux91n/

HTML is now:

```
<div id="menu">
    <button type="button" id="menu-gear" class="btn btn-default btn-block hover menu menu-rotate"><li class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-gear" aria-hidden="true"></li></button>
    <button type="button" id="menu-button-01" class="btn btn-default btn-block hover menu menu-animate"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="menu-button-02" class="btn btn-default btn-block hover menu menu-animate"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-folder-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Sometimes there isn't enough space on the screen and therefore I would like my buttons to wrap on to a next line. Ideally I would like to do this with flexbox.

Is it possible with flexbox to stack somehow buttons on top of each other and still be able to create some kind of animation?

Comment: Can you provide a rendering or example of when the buttons do not stack?

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/khuw0e5t/
The only way to stack them to my knowledge is with position:aboslute only then I lose the wrapping ability from flexbox. I could change of course with jQuery from absolute to relative but then it is not animated.